# How to run a Classic ASP file (located on a server) from VBA code?

Tags: vba, asp-classic, outlook

Last few days I was working on a Outlook 2013 function which reads an email and saves all data of the email. This is being done in the VBA code of Outlook and all works fine. The stored VBA data is then transferred to a XML file on the server which also works.

What I want to do next is read the transferred XML Data in the ASP file (which is also located on the server) and INSERT the data into an MS SQL server and then removing the XML file. 
This all works fine as well since I tested it by manually calling the asp file on the web.

Though the thing I cant seem to find out is how to activate/launch the ASP file from within the VBA code automatically instead of calling it myself manually. 
So when the Macro is being clicked in Outlook it gets the data, puts it in an XML file and then it should launch the ASP file.

There is an other way to do it, namely by using a Task Scheduler on my server which launches the ASP file every X minutes (and looks for the XML file). This possibility is something I rather avoid though because if a outlook user presses the Outlook macro multiple times in a short time the XML files will overwrite each otter (and thus having the change of not getting ALL the right data).

I didn't add my code since I think it is not really needed here (since the code I have is working), though if code is needed just ask;)

**UPDATE**
I found a piece of code which opens the asp file on the web (and thus launching it). The problem how ever is that it opens the webpage, while it only should run it. So I should add something that the page is also closed right away (so the user doesn't see it getting opened), now clue if this can be achieved though..

**The code for opening it is as follows:**

```
Private Declare Function ShellExecute _
  Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
  ByVal hWnd As Long, _
  ByVal Operation As String, _
  ByVal Filename As String, _
  Optional ByVal Parameters As String, _
  Optional ByVal Directory As String, _
  Optional ByVal WindowStyle As Long = vbMinimizedFocus _
  ) As Long

Public Sub OpenUrl()

    Dim lSuccess As Long
    lSuccess = ShellExecute(0, "Open", "http://mywebsite.nl/MyCode.asp")
End Sub
```

Comment: you could run ASP script only by opening it as "web page", of couse you should send data by using POST or GET request.

Comment: Please check this manual
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6bb4f134-ae17-4082-8140-a938414bc0c0/how-to-download-webpage-with-vba

Comment: Could you not just use the `WinHttp` to make a request to the classic asp page from VBA?

Comment: You could always convert your asp file to a vbs file. The code is mostly the same. Big difference you would instantiate objects with createobject rather than server.createobject.

Answer (score 0):

> which is also located on the server

Do you automate Outlook on the server?

It looks like you need to develop a web service for submitting your data (extracted from Outlook) to the server and run the server sider infrastructure.